# Statsmodel multinomial logistic regression outputs all nan values

Tags: regression, python, statsmodels, multinomial-logit

I'm trying to fit a multinomial logreg with statsmodel.

```
import statsmodel as sm
X = sm.add_constant(df)
logreg_model = sm.MNLogit(y[:n], X).fit()
```

Where df is a one row dataframe (just because I'm trying each variable isolately to find out which of them is causing the problem) with the following values:

```
        debt
0       0.00
1       0.00
2       0.00
3       0.00
4       0.00
5       0.00
6       0.00
7    4474.35
8       0.00
9       0.00
10      0.00
11      0.00
12      0.00
13      0.00
14      0.00
15      0.00
16   1587.51
17      0.00
18      0.00
19      0.00
20      0.00
21      0.00
22      0.00
23      0.00
24      0.00
25      0.00
26      0.00
27      0.00
28      0.00
29      0.00
30      0.00
31      0.00
32      0.00
33      0.00
34      0.00
35      0.00
36      0.00
37      0.00
38      0.00
39      0.00
40      0.00
41      0.00
42      0.00
43      0.00
44      0.00
45      0.00
46      0.00
47      0.00
48      0.00
49      0.00
```

The problem is that when I run that code, I get two warnings:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  eXB = np.column_stack((np.ones(len(X)), np.exp(X)))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  return eXB/eXB.sum(1)[:,None]
```

And the problem is that, whenever I get these warnings, MNLogit outputs this:

```
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   50
Model:                        MNLogit   Df Residuals:                       12
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                           19
Date:                Thu, 08 Jun 2023   Pseudo R-squ.:                     nan
Time:                        14:19:33   Log-Likelihood:                    nan
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -138.74
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                       nan
==============================================================================
       y=6       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const             nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
debt              nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
```

I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070816/nans-in-statsmodels-output-of-multinomial-logistic-regression) thread but didn't find any useful answer. I also tried normalizing the variable with sklearn's StandardScaler or performing log transformation but didn't work either (actually, log transformation works with this data, but when I take a larger sample, it fails too).

What can I do?

Comment: What is `y` and what is `df`? Is `df` the debt values you show? It is a little hard to diagnosis the issue without knowing the outcome values if so

Comment: Logistic regression, by definition, is for modeling responses that are zeros or ones.  In light of your data, then, it's marvelous the code produced any output at all.  Could you tell us what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a set of numerical variables (x) and an outcome (y) which is a label (it can takes int values from 0 to 10). My variables are both discrete and continue.

Since I encountered that error, I began to perform the regression with just one variable each time to get to know which of them was producing it.

df is, indeed, the values that I showed

Comment: You are telling us what procedures you have followed, but that doesn't help us help you, because clearly those procedures have failed.  They don't look appropriate for your data, either, indicating that just making the software work is unlikely to be useful (or could be misleading). If you tell us what you want to accomplish then we might be able to suggest appropriate procedures for achieving that.

Comment: Thank you and excuse me for my little clarity. The thing is: I have a dataset with information of customers (numerical variables as the amount of debt, and binary variables as whether he made or not some operation), and the type of subscription that they chose (as a categorical variable from 0-10). I want to know which of my variables are significant in order to explain the susciption type chosen.